# Python beautiful soup issue

Tags: python, html, parsing, url, beautifulsoup

Imagine that I have html with meta tag inside like

```
<meta property="og:country-name" content="South Africa"/>
```

The problem is, I need to get countrie's name from full page's html markup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url ="mydomain.com"
usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
soup = BS(data)
print soup.findAll(...
```

Can't figure out what next must be. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want `<img title="Flag of " src=""/>` instead?

Comment: Or are you searching for that tag to begin with?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No i need South Africa only :)

Comment: I need countries name from page

Comment: So you want all `<img>` tags with `Flag of` in the `title` attribute?

Comment: Can you please give us the URL. We cannot understand.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Updated question, please re-read

Comment: Sorry for update delay. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the `<meta>` tag with specific attributes:

```
country_meta = soup.find('meta', attrs={'property': 'og:country-name', 'content': True})
if country_meta:
    country = country_meta['content']
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <html><head>
...     <meta property="og:country-name" content="South Africa"/>
...     <title>Foo</title>
... </head><body></body></html>''')
>>> country_meta = soup.find('meta', attrs={'property': 'og:country-name', 'content': True})
>>> country_meta
<meta content="South Africa" property="og:country-name"/>
>>> print country_meta['content']
South Africa
```